# Injecting Entity Bean in to EJB Bean using @EJB

Tags: ejb, weblogic, eclipselink, ejb-3.0, ejb-2.x

I have Stateless Entity Beans(EJB 3.x) and EJB Beans(EJB 2.x) and other classes in my project. I want to inject Entity Bean into EJB Beans. So, far I am able to inject it using JNDI way i.e (BeanName#completename) but I want to inject it using @EJB just like we inject entity beans in another entity beans without any JNDI lookup. Both of these beans are part of different modules but deployed on same server. I am using weblogic with eclipselink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using EJB 3 or EJB 2?  EclipseLink does not support EJB 2 EntityBean, only EJB 3 Entities.

You cannot inject an Entity bean, it does not make sense, they must be queried from the database through an EntityManager.  You can inject an EntityManager using @PersistenceContext.

See,

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Runtime#Java_Enterprise_Edition

Comment: My project include both EJB 3 and EJB 2. In simple, I am trying to inject EJB 3 reference in EJB 2. Eclipse Link is only used for EJB 3.

Answer (score 1):

Entity beans are never injects in EJB beans. You can perform your DB operation on entity beans by using EntityManager. To work with database operation entities must be associated with EntityManager persistence context. so you can not work with your entities until it is not in persistence state.

All the transaction-scoped persistence context are configured by injecting @PersistentContext to EntityManager objects , like this,

```
@PersistenceContext(name="PersistentUnitName")
private EntityManager entityManager;
```